# Nichtreflexive Verwendung von "erinnern" - Amerikanismus oder nicht?

Tags: regional, reflexive

Die Frage kam auf,als ich für [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32784/odd-use-of-an) nach einer Antwort gesucht habe.

Die Überschrift sagt eigentlich schon alles: Darf man

> Ich erinnere gerne meine schöne Kindheit

sagen?

[Herr Sick](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-ich-erinnere-das-nicht-a-297352.html) (für den ich normalerweise immer einen Salzstreuer bereithalte) behauptet, das sei ein böser Amerikanismus (und führt sogar einen leicht hanebüchenen "Beweis" an), der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erinnern) sagt, "besonders norddeutsch". [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/erinnern) nennt nichtreflexiv mit Akkusativ-Objekt und ohne Präposition "umgangssprachlich" und verortet die Verwendung auch nach Norddeutschland.

Ich habe diese Form natürlich schon gehört, würde sie aber nie von mir aus verwenden.

Kann jemand mit einem norddeutschen Sprachhintergrund (sprecht ihr wirklich so komisch :) ? )mal sagen, ob der Duden recht hat oder Zwiebelfisch? Es könnte natürlich, gerade wenn es um eine norddeutsche Spezialität geht, auch sein, dass beide ein bisschen recht haben und es sich um einen "historischen Anglizismus" handelt.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28524/erinnern-or-sich-erinnern http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/kann-man-erinnern-ohne-an-auch-intransitiv-verwenden

Comment: Ich denke, es sollte *nicht transitiv* statt *nichtreflexiv* heißen, denn: *Ich erinnerte ihn an den Termin* hat mit dem vermuteten Amerikanismus und dem Beispiel nichts zu tun, oder?

Comment: Plattdeutsch hat nichtmal ein *erinnern*, stattdessen *enthollen* und *inthollen*.

Comment: @guidot oder beides? Ich denke, es ist schon klar, was gefragt ist.

Comment: Also hier Berlin völlig ungewöhnlich, aba ick bin och nich so viel im Milieu unterwegs.  Meinst du eigentlich das fehlende Reflexivpronom oder die Präposition? Es gibt die Genitivform, die vlt. etwas häufiger benutzt wird, aber den genauen Hintergrund kenne ich auch nicht:
Ich erinnere gerne meiner schönen Kindheit.

Comment: @Thomas ich meine beides fehlend, siehe Beispielsatz. Und der Genitiv geht m.A. nach nur reflexiv: *ich erinnere mich deiner*

Comment: @tofro: Er erinnere der Verstorbenen. Im Sinne einer imperativen Mahnung. ;-)

Comment: @Thomas Duden und ich kennen nur die **reflexive** Form mit Genitiv (was nix heißen muss)

Answer (score 2):

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/erinnern) listet zwei reflexive und drei transitive Bedeutungen von »erinnern« auf, wobei bei den drei transitiven Bedeutungen die dritte deinem Beispielsatz entspricht:

**reflexiv (sich erinnern):**

- mit Präpositionalobjekt: im Gedächtnis behalten haben

  > Ich erinnere mich an dich.
- mit Genitivobjekt: Erinnerung wachrufen

  > Ich erinnere mich deiner.

**transitiv (jemanden erinnern):**

- jemanden etwas nicht vergessen lassen

  > Bitte erinnere deine Frau daran, mir morgen das Buch mitzubringen.
- durch Ähnlichkeit ins Gedächtnis rufen

  > Die Form dieser Wolke erinnert mich an einen Elefanten.

**transitiv (etwas erinnern):**

- mit Akkusativobjekt; umgangssprachlich, vor allem norddeutsch: im Gedächtnis haben

  > Ich erinnere diesen Unfall.

Als Österreicher fällt es mir schwer, etwas über den Sprachgebrauch im Norden Deutschlands zu sagen. Ich kann dazu nur beitrage, dass mir der Gebrauch von »erinnern« in der zuletzt genannten Weise bis gerade eben völlig fremd war, und ohne Recherche hätte ich auch sehr selbstsicher behauptet, dass es falsch wäre. Aber offenbar gibt es Gegenden, in denen diese Form gängig ist, was sie zu einer korrekten Form macht, die eben regional begrenzt verwendet wird.

In einem Buch, das ich im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum verkaufen will, wird man dank ausgebildeter Lektoren solche Sätze nicht finden, aber vielleicht liest man solche Sätze in einer Kieler Regionalzeitung, das kann durchaus sein.

Comment: Einfaches Beispiel: "Ich erinnere das Haus." - würde ich mich fragen: Ja, an was möchten Sie das Haus denn erinnern? Wenn ich dem Haus etwas sagen möchte, ist der Akkusativ vollkommen korrekt...